# Totally stumped with "INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, uniswap, pancakeswap

I have been at this now for about a day and a half an I'm totally lost. In advance, I'm sorry if this is a simple question - I'm new to solidity (although not new to programming, blockchain and crypto in general).

I'm trying to provide some liquidity to a little shitcoin I made as a learning experiment. It worked nicely for the first few goes but then all of a sudden started throwing the error `INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED`.

Now I've gone through the actual mint function ([here](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/3b214306770e86bc3a64e67c2b5bdb566b4e94a7/contracts/PancakePair.sol#L110)) in the contract and have redone the maths/code manually about a million times and each time, the result ends up at 0 - which explains the error.

Now the question I have is how and why?

To my understanding, `reserve` will always be the `balance` of the contract (in either token) (because of the `_update` function getting called all over the place). So the variable `amount` = `balance.sub(_reserve)` ... That's 0. Then, the actual liquidity variable is being set to (roughly)  `amount.mul(_totalSupply)` which will obviously be 0 since `amount` is 0.

How will that ever be higher??

Contract address: `0x141b3c6d43acd9ccda3e2349dbfef9c821389eb9`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually thrown when you add liquidity for the first time I think.
Because reserve of both token are 0 so:

```
amount0 == amount of token0
amount1 == amount of token1

(uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves();
    uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint amount0 = balance0.sub(_reserve0);
    uint amount1 = balance1.sub(_reserve1);
```

Check and adjust your input arguments to assure  the liquidity > 0 as following condition:

```
liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);
```